# convert mysql query to codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have mysql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ms_project_log 
INNER JOIN ms_project ON ms_project_log.iwo_no = ms_project.iwo_no
WHERE  ms_project_log.iwo_no = '0007/NMS/BOTM/01/12'
ORDER BY ms_project_log.log_date DESC
```

how to convert to codeigniter active record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->join('ms_project','ms_project_log.iwo_no = ms_project.iwo_no','inner')
         ->order_by('ms_project_log.log_date','desc')
         ->get_where('ms_project_log', array('ms_project_log.iwo_no'=>'0007/NMS/BOTM/01/12'))
         ->result_array();
```

You can filter selected column using select method, by default if not using select method your query will use "select *"

Answer (score 1):

here's a code for you

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ms_project_log');
$this->db->join('ms_project','ms_project_log.iwo_no=ms_project_iwo_no', 'inner');
$this->db->where(ms_project_log.iwo_no, '0007/NMS/BOTM/01/12');
$this->db->order_by("ms_project_log.log_date", "desc"); 
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: hmm i use yanuar lutfi script, and it's work, i need an active query